# Balancing the size of oracle datafiles for a tablespace

Tags: oracle, disk-space, tablespaces

I have a tablespace where I had to add datafiles, because a partion run full. The new datafiles are not filled yet. Can I move data from one datafile to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a tablespace has multiple datafiles, Oracle manages what goes into what datafile. You have no control over this. If you have enough diskspace to do so, I suggest the following data-juggling-opperation:

- Create a new tablespace with a datafile big enough to hold all the data of your source tablespace.
- Move all the tables, indexes and other objects to this new tablespace.
- Resize the datafiles of your old tablespace how you would like them.
- Move all tables, indexes and other objects back to the resized tablespace.
- Rebuild all your indexes
- Drop the temporary tablespace you created.

Sidenote. If you had used MAXSIZE on your datafiles you would probably not have been in this situation right now... I tend to set MAXSIZE to a conservative size, since I rather run out of datafile size, than out of diskspace...

**Some tools to get you going**

Create DML statements to move your tables around

```
select distinct 'ALTER TABLE ' || owner || '.' || segment_name || ' MOVE TABLESPACE target_tablespace;'
from dba_segments 
where tablespace_name = 'old_tablespace'
and segment_type = 'TABLE';
```

Create DML statements to move your indexes around

```
select distinct 'ALTER INDEX ' || owner || '.' || index_name || ' REBUILD TABLESPACE target_tablespace;'
from dba_indexes
where tablespace_name = 'old_tablespace'
and index_type != 'LOB';
```

Resizing datafiles

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'D:\ORADATA\file.DBF' RESIZE xxxMB MAXSIZE xxxMB;
```

Rebuilding indexes

```
ALTER INDEX <SCHEMA>.<INDEX> REBUILD;
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (and simpler) solution, if you don't mind moving *all* your data to the new partition:

- Drop the new datafile.
- Move the old datafile to the new partition.
- Optional: Create a second datafile on the old partition.

Here's an excellent manual on moving datafiles around:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/renaming-or-moving-oracle-files.php#datafiles